# Javascript tree adding and deleting object or children by key in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make file stucture tree and got some problems. And then draw it with ant design tree.
Having some problems with functions to update data on my react component.

```
  {
    key: "1",
    title: "All spaces",
    type: "rootFolder",
    children: [
      {
        key: "2",
        title: "Space_1",
        type: "space",
        children: [
          { key: "3", title: "page_1", isLeaf: true, type: "page" },
          { key: "4", title: "page_2", isLeaf: true, type: "page" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: "8",
    title: "User folders",
    type: "rootFolder",
    children: [
      {
        key: "9",
        title: "User_folder_1",
        children: [
          {
            key: "10",
            title: "Space_3",
            type: "space",
            children: [
              { key: "11", title: "page_5", isLeaf: true, type: "page" },
              { key: "12", title: "page_6", isLeaf: true, type: "page" }
            ]
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I got tree like that, and need two functions
1) will get tree, node key to appen children, new children key 
it should add new children object to children of node and return tree
2) function that will get tree, object id to delete and will return new tree without deleted objects and their childrens.
Much thanks for Help!

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far

Comment: `const findById = (tree, nodeId) => {
    for (let node of tree) {
      if (node.key === nodeId) return node;

      if (node.children) {
        let desiredNode = findById(node.children, nodeId);
        if (desiredNode) return desiredNode;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };` I only got function to get element by id. But i have no idea how to push or delete it((